# How to create loop in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, while-loop, repeat

I am very new so I would need some help. Can you help me create a loop for the following actions. Click on all buttons and refresh the page and then do it 100 more times for example.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M48ue.jpg)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M48ue.jpg)

Comment: Please read this, how to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If you are vey new, try to do a loop only with prints. A simple look to your code, after click an element you will have to re-obtain desired elements cause they should change and you will get error Dom had changed

Comment: My question is if there is a way to repeat the code which I showed above many times or not since the way it is now is working without any errors?

Comment: Then if you dont wanna follow tips, my answer is, good luck

Comment: @Wonka, thanks, made me smile this day ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the minimal sample you provided, you can refactor this pretty easily. Here's how I would fix that:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# wait on buttons
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")))

buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='btn default check check green markAsChecked']")

# click buttons in a loop
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

I added a WebDriverWait between buttons, as it's better practice to wait on elements before clicking them.